# Which of the following are Hasse diagrams of lattices?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I'm trying to figure out why each of the following figures are not Hasse diagrams of lattices. Could someone, for example, explain why (A) is not a lattice? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In (A) number the vertices from top to bottom and left to right, so that the top vertex is $v_1$, the three immediately below it are $v_2,v_3$, and $v_4$, and the bottom vertex is $v_{11}$. Show that vertices $v_5$ and $v_{10}$ have no join (least upper bound).

Numbering the vertices in (B) similarly, consider $v_{11}$ and $v_{13}$: $v_3$ and $v_5$ are minimal upper bounds, but $v_{11}$ and $v_{13}$ have no join — no upper bound that is less than or equal to all upper bounds.

See if you can manage (C) on your own now. I’ve left a bit of a hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Two of the vertices in the bottom row of four will work.

Answer (score 0):

The following theorem about partially ordered sets ("posets") is helpful.

> **Theorem:** Suppose $P$ is a finite poset. Consider two elements $x,y \in P$ that don't have a join; so $x \vee y$ doesn't exist. Then
>   either:
>
> - $x$ and $y$ have no upper bound
> - $x$ and $y$ have two or more (distinct) minimal upper bounds.

Therefore, my hint is:

**Hint:** To show that a finite poset isn't a lattice, look for pairs of elements that have two or more (distinct) minimal upper bounds.